# help please with if condition

Tags: soql

On the Opportunity object, I have a Quick action that generates a pdf file using a ContentDocument (the else block) and creates a new version of the ContentDocument (the if block). I need the following condition: if the file already exists in the system with this name, create a new version of it.

I think we need to use soql query, extract name from ContentDocument, if there is such name, that is query != null, create its new version with if block, else create pdf file with such name.

I couldn't get soql query into if logic, so I created custom object on which I created field, trying to extract title from ContentVersion where Title Opportunity.Invoice_Number__c. (The file name is stored in Invoice_Number__c&Opportunity)

My code creates a new version if there's already a file with this name, BUT if there's no file with this name, it won't create me a ContentDocument giving me an error

message: "List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

stackTrace: "Class.controllerTest.savePDF: line 11, column 1"

Line: invoice.ConName__c=[select Title from ContentVersion where Title=: opps.Invoice_Number__c].id;

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOQL always returns a list, it may be empty or have a value.

`[SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Title =: fileName]` This will return a `List<ContentVersion>`

But if you write it like this:

`Id contentDocumentId = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Title =: fileName].ContentDocumentId;`

This will first make SOQL try to fetch a record and from that record fetch ContentDocumentId. So if you dont have a record in DB it will fail with `List has no rows for assignment to SObject`, which means SOQL tried to fetch the row and assign it to `ContentVersion`, but was unable to do so.

To avoid this:

Make sure to let SOQL always return a List.

```
List<ContentVersion> contentVersions = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Title =: fileName];
if(!contentVersions.isEmpty()){
    Id contentDocumentId = contentVersions.get(0).ContentDocumentId;
    // Logic goes here
}
```

Comment: thank you, that's work.